# enum defined in PCL throws error in Web API service

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I have a PCL targeting .NET 4.6 and Windows 10.  Inside the PCL there is an enum defined as follows:

```
namespace Shared.User
{
    public enum PermissionType
    {
      System,
      Account,
      Site,
      Queue
    }
}
```

Ive added the PCL to a Asp.NET Web API 2 project, and when I try to do a comparison I get this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Shared.User.PermissionType [MyWebServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b9f7c69b7e2ca2dc]' to 'Shared.User.PermissionType [Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b9f7c69b7e2ca2dc]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) MyWebServices
```

I'm lost as to what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

In the error message it looks like the types are the same but the assembly that they're compiled into are different, with the comparison being against 'MyWebServices' and 'Shared'.